# Sharing variables between C and Javascript for real-time dashboard

Tags: javascript, c, dashboard

What is a clean and fast way to share states/variables between a backend written in C and a dashboard/frontend written in Javascript?
When using server-client setup, I used `websocket` to communicate. But now we want to integrate it into the same hardware, thus not requiring the server-client setup.

Given that the variables are changed in our C-backend a few times per second, how can we read these into our Javascript?

**Exact set-up:**

We have a controller which is receiving packets from sensors. The controller is calculating some variables from these packets in our C backend. These backend variables ought to be shared on the front-end to a dashboard, written in Javascript, to move some gauges and stuff.

The only thing I need share are these `global` C variables.

Comment: The answer will depend on exactly how you're using the C code and the JavaScript code on the "same hardware." Are you using something like [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org)? You can write and use C++ modules in Node.js, which is used by the main process. (Electron has a main process that's server-like, and one or more renderer processes that are browser-like.) Etc. I think the question probably is too broad and open /ended for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: Edited for a bit more clarity